# How to filter the dates in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe:

```
Year    Month
2021    06/01/2021
2021    06/01/2021
2021    07/01/2021
2021    07/01/2021
2021    0/01/2021
2021    0/01/2021
```

I need a dataframe for specific months along with '0/01/2021'. Tried with below code:

```
df=df.filter((col('Month')=='07/01/2021') & (col('Month')=='0/01/2021'))
display(df)
```

My required dataframe is:

```
Year    Month
2021    07/01/2021
2021    07/01/2021
2021    0/01/2021
2021    0/01/2021
```

But I'm getting:
`Query returned no results`
as result.
The 'Month' column is in string format.
How to filter for these dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. You are asking for each line that the value equal both 07/01/2021 AND (`&`) 0/01/2021.
What you are the lines where month = 07/01/2021 OR (`|`) 0/01/2021:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

a = [
    (2021, "06/01/2021"),
    (2021, "06/01/2021"),
    (2021, "07/01/2021"),
    (2021, "07/01/2021"),
    (2021, "0/01/2021"),
    (2021, "0/01/2021"),
]

b = "Year", "Month"

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)
df = df.filter((col("Month") == "07/01/2021") | (col("Month") == "0/01/2021"))
# 
df.show()
+----+----------+                                                               
|Year|     Month|
+----+----------+
|2021|07/01/2021|
|2021|07/01/2021|
|2021| 0/01/2021|
|2021| 0/01/2021|
+----+----------+
```

you can also write is like this :

```py
df.filter(col("Month").isin("07/01/2021", "0/01/2021")).show()
```